# To get the most frequent levels in a data frame

Tags: r

I have the data frame like

[image]

now i need to get the output with most frequently occurred levels like

[image]

Could any one help me on this please??

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far and where you got stuck? `table` might be useful ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this with dplyr

```
set.seed(43)
df<-data.frame(location=sample(LETTERS[1:3],20,replace=TRUE),
               site=sample(c("bang","mys","hubl","dar"),20,replace=TRUE))

library(dplyr)
df%>%group_by(location,site)%>%summarize(Count=n())%>%arrange(desc(Count))%>%slice(1)%>%ungroup()%>%select(location,site)
```

Comment: Thanks,The code worked but i am seeing lot of new functions like arrange,slice etc,Can you please help me how can i learn more on dplyr package as i cant remember so many functions by heart

Comment: you can watch this two part video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWjqLW-u3hc on dplyr and this is good tutorial video on tidyr and dplyr https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/data-wrangling-with-r-and-rstudio/

Comment: search for "dplyr cheatsheet"

Answer (score 3):

We can use `Mode` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode)

```
 Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

and use it in any of the group by functions.  One option is with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(location) %>% 
   summarise(site = Mode(site))
#    location  site
#     <chr> <chr>
#1        a  site
#2        b  bang
#3        c  site
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
with(df, tapply(as.character(site), location, FUN = Mode))
```

#### data

```
 df<-data.frame(location=rep(letters[1:3], c(3, 1, 2)),
     site = c("site", "site", "bang", "bang", "site", "bang"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Code is fine but this is not working if the location has only one site and the occurrence is only one ,i am getting NA for those

Comment: @SandeepShetty  I tried with an example that mimics your situation, but I am not getting NAs (you can check the update)