# How to count number of times value appears in column for each unique id?

Tags: r

I have dataframe with id and desicion of yes and no, for example

```
a <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), val = c("y","y","y","n","n","n","n","y","n","n","y","y"))
```

[original data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3iGt.png)

I want to output for each unique id the most repeated value. i.e example of result for this dataframe would be

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), val = c("y","n","y"))[result][2]
```

or

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), val = c("y","n","n"))
```

Any help is appreciated
thanks in advance!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29255473/5325862) and its linked posts might help you get started

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32684931/5325862) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37944044/5325862)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most frequent value (mode) by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255473/most-frequent-value-mode-by-group)

Answer (score 0):

We can do a group by 'id' and apply the `Mode` on 'val'

```
library(dplyr)
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 }

a %>% 
     group_by(id) %>% 
     summarise(val = Mode(val))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     id val  
#  <dbl> <fct>
#1     1 y    
#2     2 n    
#3     3 n
```

---

Or using only `base R`

```
aggregate(val ~ id, a, Mode)
#   id val
#1  1   y
#2  2   n
#3  3   n
```

Answer (score 0):

another option

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  count(id, val) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  top_n(1, n) %>% 
  select(-n)
```